# stuck while installing ubuntu 16.10

Tags: uefi

hi am geting  an error whiling fresh installing ubuntu 16.10 on my hp pavilion laptop

```
[ 16.222192] scsi host2: runtime PM trying to activate child device host2 but pareny (2-4:1.0) is not active
```

after displaying this error for1 sec ubuntu logo appear and and then nothing happen next stuck at ubuntu logo 
am booting UEFI mode

[image]

Comment: Check the drives mode in UEFI. IF RAID change to AHCI.

Comment: Installing 16.10 on Acer Swift 3 and I get the same error at the end of the installation. Then it just hangs. The disk is not bootable afterwards.

Comment: my laptop not allow me to do that to change RAID to AHCI  try with lubuntu have the same problem