# ubuntu boot file missing after upgrade from 16.04 to 16.10

Tags: boot, dual-boot, uefi, amd-graphics

laptop config Amd A10-8700p apu with r7m360 card with uefi Gpt partsion
during install ubuntu 16.10 i got this error

> Blockquote[ 16.222192] scsi host2: runtime PM trying to activate child device host2 but pareny (2-4:1.0) is not active

here is the link of details of this error which i face a month ago while try a fresh install 16.10 [problem details with fresh install](https://askubuntu.com/questions/838213/stuck-while-installing-ubuntu-16-10?noredirect=1#comment1282147_838213)

so i can't install 16.10  also try with lubuntu and xbuntu got same error,
 but i can easily install 16.04 so i install 16.04 with dual boot with windows 10 
and after install i use distro update command to upgrade to 16.10 but after complete all update when system ask for reboot and after reboot my ubuntu boot menu missing i directly got entry to windows and even press F9 for boot menu their is no ubuntu boot entry . 
is it a bug of ubuntu 16.10  or its windows 10 force me to stop install ubuntu ?

Comment: This seems like two questions, and this format works best with single questions -- you might want to edit down to the one you need answered first, then ask the second one separately.

Comment: actually i already ask the first qustion before a month http://askubuntu.com/questions/845483/ubuntu-boot-file-missing-after-upgrade-from-16-04-to-16-10 but my question is is windows  prevent me to install ubuntu or its a ubuntu bug ? first problem is a referral

Comment: If that's the question you're asking now, then ask that question, with a suitable link to the older one.  You'll get better answers, and they're more likely to be useful to others in the future.

Comment: ok sure  i will try my best to do that am new this forum so correct me :)

Comment: Seems significantly clearer now what you're actually asking.  :)